# How do I simulate that the emulator has as an SD Card?

Tags: android, emulation

Can I simulate an sdcard presence in the android emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered in the [Emulator Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard).

The emulated SD Card image is single file which the Emulator reads to and writes from.

You can specify to create an SD Card when you create the [Android Virtual Device (AVD)](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) using the [`android` GUI](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#android) (for example from within Eclipse by clicking the [image] button):

[image]

Or you can create an SD Card using the [`mksdcard` command](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#mksdcard).

To use an SD Card image when you start your emulator pass the `-sdcard` option to the `emulator` command:

```
emulator -sdcard c:/path/to/my/sdcard
```

If you're using the `android` GUI to start your Emulators you need to have specified the SD Card when you created your AVD.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Eclipse Plugin (ADT) has a graphical interface that will assist you with the creation of emulator images with SD cards. I believe it is called DDMS.

You can find the plugin here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simulate the presence of an SD card by using a disk image file. There are more details [in the emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).