# Testing performance of an Android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test the performance of an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application)

How can i test the performance of an android application ? Is there any tool that i can make use of ?

Comment: you beat me by 60 seconds, mate! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) Tool.

This tool is very handy at identifing performance bottlenecks.  The link also covers how to create and view trace files in TraceView