# Android performance testing

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test the performance of an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application)

The test cases on launch performance in android source code are extending android.test.LaunchPerformanceBase but i can not able to make use of that class in my application test cases... Do anybody knows how to make use of that class?

These performance test cases are present in development/apps/launchperf, please look into these test cases and give me the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class isn't publicly available in the SDK (which it isn't), then it's not really intended for use.

You could refer to this question for some information about Android performance testing:
[How to test the performance of an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-do-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application)

That should allow you to measure specific parts of your application performance, including its launch performance.