# Calculate time for TextView rendering performance

Tags: android, rendering

How do I calculate the time needed for `TextView` to render a line of text?

```
textView.setText("hello");
```

Comment: Record time before and after the method call. But, how would is it going to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend TextView class and override draw:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    //log start time
    super.draw(canvas);
    //log end time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Traceview in eclipse

Comment: Check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Maxim is to just log before and after `setText("hello");`

```
Log.i(logTag, "start time");
textView.setText("hello");
Log.i(logTag, "end time");
```

This won't work if the view is only rendered after the call to `setText` though. Maybe someone can confirm or deny that in a comment.