# TraceView file has no data

Tags: android, android-traceview

I have added `Debug.startMethodTracing("can_act");` in `onCreate` and `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` in `onDestroy`.The trace file is of size 0KB.

What went wrong?

## EDIT:

It writes out a trace file but it is of size 0 KB.I use the methods in a custom Camera activity on a device.I am calling it after `super.onDestroy();`

Comment: Any help in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application ?

Comment: I am tracing on a device for a camera