# performance evaluation of android os

Tags: android, performance, testing, operating-system

I want to evaluate the performance of my auto android os . I want to detect the cost time of gdi. i.e. time int operation takes? similarly the time float operation takes etc. I also want to detect other items.How should i approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test the performance of an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application)

Comment: I want to evaluate the performance of my auto android os,not the application.

Comment: One system is composed by each application.http://blog.csdn.net/pugongying1988/article/details/9279997