# Any tools or services to profile Cordova-AngularJS applications written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, analytics

Is there any tool or online service available to help profile javascript applications written with Cordova, AngularJS & Ionic? Or what do you use to attain the same objective?

My objectives are measuring execution times, crash or errors, memory consumption, processor usage, data consumption. I don't want to insert instrumentation code throughout the application and make it a practice for others involved in the team, and am looking for a drop-in solution like how New Relic and the like work. Since much of our development is done in text editors and not IDEs we also cannot use any IDE-only feature.

I tried looking around and didn't find any serious solution hence the question.

Comment: This depends on your testing-device. For android this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957135/how-to-test-the-performance-of-an-android-application

Comment: Test devices can be measured with some work, but we want to gather data post-deployment so an online service which provides libraries to link would be more like it. Just can't find one.

Comment: I don't understand. Your code has to run on a specific device to be measured. You are talking about performance aren't you. So if i say let your app run locally and use chromes profiler it wouldn't help much right? cause you want to know how the app runs in a specific environment?

Comment: If a tool provides platform specific averages or crash reports with platform details, like how a lot of website analytics tools provide, that'll do. We can't rely on numbers reported for a few test environments available in-house.